# Why does "sudo rm -r /example/*" return "No such file or directory" when content exists?

Tags: rm

I am using an Amazon Linux 2 distribution and trying to delete the contents of `/opt/atlassian/jira/work` directory using the following command

```
sudo rm -r /opt/atlassian/jira/work/*
```

The command returns:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/atlassian/jira/work/*’: No such file or directory"
```

The directory exists and it contains another directory `Catalina` which I verified with LS:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSt7p.png)

I tried the command without the `*`:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/atlassian/jira/work/
```

But it just deleted the directory (work) which is not what I want.

If this is a permissions issue, how do I use sudo to get around that?

Comment: What is the output of `ls /opt/atlassian/jira/work` (_without_ `sudo`)?

Comment: What is the output of 'getenforce'?  ie is SELinux blocking access?

Comment: Output of `ls /opt/atlassian/jira/work` is permission denied

Comment: Output of `getenforce` is Disabled

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).